# How can I make null values be considered as MAX in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

To be able to explain the situation, let's say I have a table

```
Product price
Cola    2
Cola    null
Fanta    1
Fanta    2
Sprite   2
Sprite null
```

I need to write a query that would return the maximum price per product and if the price is null, would consider it the maximum.
So for this table it should return Cola null, Fanta 2, Sprite null.

I really appreciate your help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What syntax? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: Standard SQL. thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard SQL allows you to specify where `NULL` values should be sorted using the expression `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAST` in the `ORDER BY` statement. This can be combined with a window function to get the desired behaviour:

```
select product, price
from (
   select product,
          price,
          row_number() over (partition by product order by price desc nulls first) as rn
   from products
) t
where rn = 1
order by product, price desc nulls first
;
```

With Postgres it is usually faster to use `distinct on` for this kind of queries:

```
select distinct on (product) product, price
from products
order by product, price nulls first
```

Comment: +1 . . . The `distinct on` method is particularly appropriate for Postgres.

Answer (score 7):

```
select product, case when sum(case when price is null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                     then null
                     else max(price)
                end as price
from your_table
group by product
```

Answer (score 3):

I decided to take the following approach.  Of course, you will need to decide what "type" your price column is and make the max of the column equal to the max value within the DBMS you are using.

```
SELECT product, NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(price, 2147483647)),2147483647) as max_price
FROM product_pricing
GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
select product, 
    case when (count(*) - count(price)) > 0 then null else max(price) end as max_price
from t
group by product
```

here the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ea15b/1/0

Answer (score -2):

```
create table #test(
prod varchar(10),
qty int
)

insert #test(prod, qty)
values ('Cola', 2), ('Cola', NULL), ('Fanta', 1), ('Fanta', 2)

select case when max(s.qty) = 9999999 then NULL else max(s.qty) end, 
    s.prod
from (select coalesce(qty, 9999999) as qty, prod from #test) s
group by prod
```